# SSD Cache probabely not doing its job

Tags: ssd

I have an Asus s400 with a 24gb SSD for caching. As far as I know this cache drive should be used when RAM is over-weighted, right? I have a 4gb RAM, 2.5 of which is occupied by Win8 itself, leaving a not usually enough space for my other apps, and as a result, I expected the SSD cache to have a lot of activity caching the extra data and getting them back to the RAM frequently... an expectation that was fully discouraged, when I accidentally found out lately that its activity is almost always %0, as opposed to my HDD, which takes me a lot of time when I switch between my already run, high memory using apps.I downloaded the driver for Intel RST from Asus website (and the one provided by Intel website failed to work for me since my system doesn't support RAID) and installed it successfully, with no change in the problem after rebooting, nor having access to the IRST control panel. (and then doubted if the driver was already installed!!)
 It is a SanDisk U100 SSD, and ExpressCache is also installed apparently, as shown up by `eccmd -info` statement. The cpu is a 1.8gh core i5, and as the last tip, it is taking about 30 secs to hibernate, and a less time, maybe about 15 to 20 sec to boot again from hibernate mode.
What's going wrong here?! Do I have any options other than enhancing my RAM?!

Comment: The SSD caches data from your “mechanical” hard drive. This may or may not include swap.

Comment: You mean it caches the frequently used apps for a faster loading? How can I check it? And, there's no way to force it include swap as well?!!!

Comment: Yes, that’s one way to put it. I only worked with ExpressCache once and don’t have that device anymore, so I can’t give you further help. Still, `eccmd` might be able to list cached files.

Comment: Thank's a lot... Anyway, I suppose there should be a difference between ExpressCache, which preloads files from HDD, and the Intel RST, which is my current challenge...